# Remote reindex API AWS ElasticSearch Null Pointer Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, reindex, amazon-elasticsearch

I am trying to move one index from an older cluster with ES 5.3 to different cluster ES 7.10 using remote reindexing api both are in the same VPC

```
curl -X POST \https://target.com/_reindex \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "https://source.com:443"
    },
    "index": "ind1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "ind1"
  }
}'
```

I am getting this error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null}],"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null},"status":500}
```

I cannot just take the snapshot and migrate as 5.3 indices aren't supported at 7.10

Answer (score 1):

Reindex requires `_source` to be enabled for all documents in the source indices. it seems you disable `_source` and you could not reindex from this indices.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html

Comment: can you give a link or a reference? "how am i supposed to enable _source

Comment: @quickshekhar as I know you cannot enable _source for indexed documents.

Comment: you cannot, it needs to be enabled from when you first index the data